# Add lines to the top of a memo in Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, lines, tmemo

The function `Memo.Lines.Add('Some text')` in Delphi adds the string to the bottom of the memo. Is there any function which adds the text to the top?

For example, if the `Lines` property of the Memo contains:

```
string 1
string 2
string 3
```

I want to add a string `string 0` before `string 1`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Lines` property is a [`TStrings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings) instance that supports inserting at a specified line number. The method to do so is [`Insert`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Insert) and is called like this:

```
Memo.Lines.Insert(0, 'string 0');
```